# Where can I access and manage downloaded themes in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I downloaded and installed several themes on Google Chrome. Now how can I see the list of themes that I just downloaded? And how can I switch to one of them without downloading it again?

Answer (score 12):

Here are the steps to see installed/downloaded extensions/themes:

1. Open Google Chrome browser and login into it or alternatively login into Google Account by using which you have downloaded the extensions/themes.
2. Open [My Extensions & Apps](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/user/purchases).
3. Under ["Installed"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/user/purchases) tab, you will find the list of active extensions/themes. The currently installed theme shows up here. Under ["Library"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/user/library) tab you will find the list of downloaded but not in use extensions/themes. The previously installed themes shows up here.

Comment: This is the actual solution, guys. Old themes will show up under Library. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK there is no way to manage themes like you would apps that you have downloaded. Once you click on "Choose Theme" it will download the crx and then overwrite whatever theme you had previously installed.

By going to `Settings` you will see a section called `Appearance`, however the only revert option is to revert to default.

One way of keeping, managing, and sharing the themes you choose is to go tot he themes page and share the theme you are installing with either your Gmail or Google+. This will at least provide a way to track which themes you like, and it will keep all of the links to the themes in 1 place. Here are the steps to share with a blank circle to keep it private.

- Go to `Settings > Appearance`
- Select "Get Themes"
- Find one you want and hover over the card. Next to the "Choose Theme"  button, select the "Share" button
- Share the theme with Google+
- Choose to share the theme with a Circle that only you are a member of, that way all the posts will be visible only by you

Now when you visit Google+ (or Gmail if you choose to share via email) you will have a list of all the themes you've tried or want to try in the future.

Comment: Clever workaround!

Comment: There is no Google+ anymore

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/)
2. Click the settings icon in the top right:

   [image]
3. Select *Your Apps*

Comment: not shown anymore i guess(?),now you can see only extensions and apps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to browse your installed themes as you can only install one theme at a time, the closest you can get currently is the following:

1. Chrome web store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/user/library
2. Press the cog on the left of your email on the top right
3. This reveals *installed* extensions and themes (but only the currently installed theme)
4. Press the "Library" tab to see extensions and themes you've used in the past
5. This list contains your previously used themes, use F3 and type "Theme" and F3 again to step through your themes :-)

Hope this helps until Google adds a native feature!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "theme manager" of a sort. Find the theme you want in the store. Click it one time. The description window will open. Bookmark this link. In the bookmark tab create a new folder and label it themes. Now when you want to go back to a previous theme all you need to do is go to your bookmarks. You are all finished. Simply bookmark each theme into this folder as you find them. Oh, its easier to access them if you enable the bookmarks bar. I sincerely hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sign in to  your Google account.

Either go to [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/user/purchases#themes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/user/purchases) > Themes directly or through chrome://settings  > Get themes button.

Your history of the installed themes are in plain sight.

[The screenshot of the extensions list, with the URL visible and the themes higlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xof0k.png)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state, and confirming this answer is not already answered in one of the existing answers on the post if applicable.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Not true! This just show the current installed theme

Comment: currently on that link - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/user/purchases#themes it shows only installed apps and extensions, there not installed\downloaded themes...

Answer (score 1):

To se all downloaded Themes and Extensions
*(you must be logged in to your google account), simply go to web store, on top right corner there will be your gmail address and next to it is setting button click on it and then select My Extensions and Apps.

Chrome Web Store > Settings > My Extensions and Themes

is you login in to google recently and trying this you might find your themes in My Extensions and Themes, but you need to download them if you haven't downloaded it on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder in bookmarks and name it Themes.  Save the bookmark of each theme you want to use, or to keep available.

When you want to change themes:

1. Go to settings.
2. Click appearance.
3. Click reset to default.
4. Go to the bookmark for the theme you wish to use and click "install".  All user restrictions will have been removed when you reset the last theme to default.

It is quick and works for me.   ☺

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting on such an old thread.

There is a trick that may work to see what Themes you have installed on your Chrome.

Go to the Search box on the left column, and type keywords that you use when you look for a Theme.

Then select the Themes button.

The difference is that now, in this listing your already installed themes have a green flag saying 'ADDED', and a 'rate it' green button on the right.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Themes aren't saved to the browser. 
When one is overwritten it's gone and must be redownloaded at the Chome Web Store if desired again.

However, if you input a valid keyword into the Chrome Web Store search bar at the top left of the screen (ex. Disney or Cats) and have 'themes' ticked, those you've downloaded before will appear with a green 'added' ribbon over the thumbnail and a 'rate' button in place of the 'add to Chrome' button.

Answer (score 0):

> Now how can I see the list of themes that I just downloaded?

Themes do show up in `chrome://system` > `Extensions` row > click `Expand` button. However, they are jumbled with regular extensions and may not be easy to distinguish by name.

Assuming you're using Windows, here's a `cmd` you can copy and paste that should give you a  list:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %a in (`where /F /R "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data" manifest.json`) do @findstr /I /M /C:"theme" %a >nul 2>&1 && @findstr /C:"\"name\"" %a
```

For me, I get this output:

```
"name": "Morpheon Dark",
```

I've assumed manifests containing the word `theme` means it is a theme, but this might raise some false positive if normal extensions also contain `theme`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your frustrations, and I know I had seen away to mix and match themes with base colors, etc..  Then I open a new tab, in the lower right corner there is a button that says "customize chrome".  That opens a panel on the right and in there you can switch themes, change the colors and still keep backgrounds, etc..

The button:

[image: Button]

The panel:

[image: Panel]

Answer (score -1):

If u have crx file then right click on it choose open with chrome and then choose to save at the below section of chrome. Then a pop up appears. Select add. The theme will be applied

Answer (score -1):

Search for and install from the Chrome Webstore (Extension Manager/ Switcher) that allows viewing of Installed Extensions and browse through your extensions and hopefully find one that links to your Installed Themes.

Comment: Does not work. Themes are not listed under Extensions.